# Вывод данных

Tags: android, java

При `System.out.println("Blog: " + TitleNews.text());` выводит все записи, которые есть в логкат, но в `Text.setText("Blog: " + TitleNews.text());` выводит последнюю запись, как сделать, чтоб выводились все, заранее спасибо.

**Добавлено.**

Мне нужно, чтоб в textview выводило все строки,

```
for (Element newsheader: newsheaders) {
    Element TitleNews = newsheader.select("a").first();
    Text.setText("Blog: " + TitleNews.text());
    System.out.println("Blog: " + TitleNews.text());
}
```

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: разберись лучше где ты и в чем накосячил и правильно именую методы и переменные..

Comment: не поможешь все значения titlenews распределить по ListView

Comment: Уже не надо, сделал =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну все правильно работает =)

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList();
for(Element newsheader : newsheaders){ 
Element TitleNews = newsheader.select("a").first(); 
arr.add(TitleNews.text()+"/n");
System.out.println("Blog: " + TitleNews.text()); 
}

Text.setText("Blog: " + arr.toString());
```